# Differences between online optimization and realtime optimization

Tags: optimization

I want to know what differences between online and real-time optimization.
I think in real time system disturbance and uncertainty must be considered even in every moment. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the answers hold also true for optimization: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304780/online-vs-realtime

Comment: I think you might be interested in dynamic online learning. You might check out discussions here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385159/regret-in-online-learning/458987#458987